# How do I add an "At Sign Search" to Firefox 68?

Tags: firefox, search, address-bar, omnibox

Firefox has a really neat "at-sign search" feature where, for some search engines, if you preface a search with `@[engine_tag]`, the search will take place *on that site* instead of in the default search engine. It seems like the documentation on that feature is lacking on Mozilla's site - where in the Firefox preferences can these tags be set? It seems like the "keyword" portion of the search preferences *sort of* fills this role, but it doesn't have the autocomplete features of the at-sign search. Pic links below to show what I'm talking about:

List of all "at sign search engines":
[image: list of all "at sign search engines"]

Typing in an "at sign search engine" name:
[image: typing in an "at sign search engine" name]

Searching the engine:
[image: searching the engine]

Result of the search:
[image: result of the search]

Comment: Thanks fixer1234. I would have inlined the images, but I'm rep-poor.

Comment: You're just going to have to create more great posts like this one so you can get more rep.  :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The search engine list is available in the settings under the **Search** category.  Below the list of available search engines is a link to find more which will take you to the [search tools section](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search-tools/) of the add-on's website.  Adding and removing search engines is documented on the support site under [Add or remove a search engine in Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/add-or-remove-search-engine-firefox).

After adding a search engine to the list of available ones, you can add it to the @ list by creating a keyword for it that begins with @.  This is also done in the preferences area search engine list by double-clicking the keyword column next to the search engine and entering the desired word.  This is documented at [Assign shortcuts to search engines](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/assign-shortcuts-search-engines)

If you're looking to make your own search engine available for your site, that can be done via the [OpenSearch description format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/OpenSearch).